# C# How To Embed And Reference An External Assembly (DLL)

Tags: c#, dll

Im trying to embed one DLL files to my main application(.exe)
Here is my program.cs snippet:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Reflection;

namespace testapp
{


static class Program
{
    public static string versioncode = "2";
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);


        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args) =>
        {
            String thisExe = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;
            System.Reflection.AssemblyName embeddedAssembly = new System.Reflection.AssemblyName(args.Name);
            String resourceName = thisExe + "." + embeddedAssembly.Name + ".dll";

            using (var stream = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
            {
                Byte[] assemblyData = new Byte[stream.Length];
                stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);
                return System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
            }
        };

        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

}

I am trying to embed DLL named as "ThirdDemo.dll", already added as reference and Copy Local=false also i add as a additional file not just a reference and Build Action=Embedded Resource.

But i got this error when i compile:

[image]

stream, null.

Comment: `GetManifestResourceStream` is for loading an embedded resource. Have you checked it’s listed in `GetManifestResourceNames()` and the name you’re using is correct?

Comment: Where do I need to put the "ThirdDemo.dll" part in the code?

Answer (score 1):

I asume that the `resourceName` is incorrect because you get a null stream from `GetManifestResourceStream()`. This normally happens if you try to load a resource that does not exist.

You could use something like ILspy (https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy/releases) to open your compiled .exe and lookup the correct name of your embedded resource.

Comment: I am trying to embed this file "ThirdDemo.dll" but i cant figured out, which places to change the code to point "ThirdDemo.dll"

Comment: Why don't you just copy the ThirdDemo.dll into the same directory where your .exe is?

Comment: It's already there but I want to publish it as a single .exe. I have problems running when I use applications like ILmerge

Comment: You probably just need to do System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("MyProgram.ThirdDemo.dll") but the easist way is to look into the compiled .exe with a tool like ILSpy to find the correct Resource name if you are not sure how it got embedded

Comment: It worked with your way, but same logic in the code I shared above, but why didn't it work?

Comment: Set a breakpoint at String resourceName = thisExe + "." + embeddedAssembly.Name + ".dll"; and look what resouceName realy contains. I asume that somthing there contains a value that you didn't expect

Comment: thank you so much you saved my day, keep up the good work

Comment: also, you should sign this exe, or literally every antivirus program will shut this down for strange self concealable behaviour